# What category of peer-reviewed journals are more receptive to the idea of Conceptual Review Articles?

Tags: peer-review, paper-submission, review-articles

Given my personal experience, it boils down to the task of finding an open-minded editor/journal.

"**Conceptual Papers:** *can bridge existing theories in interesting ways, link work across disciplines, provide multi-level insights, and broaden the scope of our thinking* "

I was searching online for science journals accepting articles on subjects that are not in mainstream academic research areas. While 'new ideas' are acceptable in research articles on finance, education, psychology. I could not find anything similar for engineering journals.

Comment: I'll reopen since it's no longer a shopping question which was the original close reason, though I can't promise that it will be well-received.

Comment: If you're quoting from a source, you should ideally make the original source/author clear with a link or citation.

Comment: The body of the question now seems like an answer, whereas it should have been posted as a question, together with a possible (self-written) answer.

Comment: I am afraid we cannot really help you here: While there are categories of journals in some fields, whether such a categorisation exists and particularly the categories themselves are field-dependent. What use is it for you if another field has just the right category of journals for you, but that category simply doesn’t exist in your field? Only somebody familiar with your particular paper and the journal landscape in your field can help you. If there is nobody like that, all you can do is take an intensive look at all the journals of your field – as tedious as that may be.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft -I guess what I was really looking for was tips on how to swim against a strong current. But, it looks like this forum is a representation of this strong current and it is difficult to even discuss something that the common opinion views as unstandard or even abnormal.

Comment: *I guess what I was really looking for was tips on how to swim against a strong current.* – Well, that’s not what you’ve been asking for (and it would require more details on the current you are feeling to swim against). — *this forum is a representation of this strong current* – The vast majority of people here are not from your field. How should they represent or oppose the current you are swimming against? — *it is difficult to even discuss something …* – This site is not about how academia is, not how it should be. Also, it is generally not suited for discussions.

Comment: @TheMatrixEquation-balance that is exactly what my answer is telling you, you believe you have a useful idea, but it's unusual and so you encounter resistance when propose it. The first thing you should ask is why does it encounter resistance (and not just say because its new) and try to counter those challenges. Just because something is new doesn't mean its better (that's a appeal to novelty fallacy), but something that is new may have other problems if it isn't thought out properly (and that is not a fallacy).

Comment: Based on your other questions and comments you use newspaper articles for an academic paper, this isn't good for academia because you should be going to whatever they are referencing instead of them (journalism tends to be descriptive, not analytic). Given you want to connect explosive mining to space mining, based on my not expertise knowledge of the field, have you considered how a lack of oxygen changes things, what about the lack of gravity and friction afterwards, what is the cost/benefit of transporting explosives over traditional drills, can the explosives be manufactured in space, ect?

Comment: @NAMcMahon - you have asked exact questions that my article examines in terms of existing rock engineering technologies and experience. But the uniqueness of this situation is that we (my co-author) are working in a complete vacuum of research. There are no published papers on this subject. But a NASA engineer who first saw my assay with a proposal for an iron-nickel rock landing independently, that would remove scalability concerns, told me: "No budget, No research".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the question here should really be "What are the minimal requirements for a conceptual paper to be a worthy addition to the academic literature". Academic literature is very different to everyday literature where when you want to introduce an idea to people you write an article for a newspaper or a blog post. In academia all ideas being introduced, including conceptual ideas, need solid evidence not just it would be worth working towards. Looking for an "open-minded editor/journal" probably more likely to lead you to you finding somewhere worthless, crackpoty or predatory which you end up submitting your article, ruining your reputation and/or losing you money.

When thinking about conceptual ideas, keep in mind that ideas/questions are cheap, implementation is key.  You may also have heard that the key thing for research is a good idea/question, and I also agree with that, but its a *good* idea/question that's worthwhile. And a good idea/question is essentially one that is easy to implement, since most ideas/questions are hard to find anything academically useful from.

So what should we have in a conceptual paper, probably the simplest thing is evidence and an understanding of how it's building on previous academic work. If you think the field should adopt a new idea or more people should start investigating this topic then you need solid arguments as to why this idea isn't stupid and starting points from which researchers could build upon. Generally I would guess back of the envelope calculations or early and incomplete data could possibly be sufficient here however they still need to be solid and robust to challenges. When talking about the new idea/question it needs to be able to link back to previous work to support it or needs to do a literature review to show that tool X from field A could probably be hacked together to be useful in field B, and the back of the envelope calculations could support this. The conceptual article should also point out how this could be a natural progression of the field and list the possible problems with the idea to try to help others see where the struggles would be or speed up with the debunking of this idea. It could also propose some solid *good* questions that the author thinks would be valuable to answer but doesn't have the time/skill/resources to do so. But for this to be a worthwhile piece of academic work the context is very important, a new idea with only back of the envelope calculations isn't a research article, its a project proposal at best.

Once you ask what is needed to make the research solid then being unable to find a relevant journal should either go away or become an issue of the research not being solid enough to be of interest. No need to search for "open-minded" places.

Comment: "N A McMahon" - I enjoy reading your answer. It is elegant, smart and thoughtful. But it does not extend from the entrenched position that science can only exist in budgeted academic areas of research. In my case, I am looking for a niche (journal) a bit beyond that.

Comment: If you don't have a budget for X then you can't pay people to seriously think about X. If you can't pay people to seriously think about X then X cannot be academic. If you want to talk about something that hasn't even got fields it can sprout from being researched yet then this isn't academic and should go in a blog or a forum or a news article. If you still want to make this academic then you will need to go back to whatever fields you think would give rise to fields that give rise to your target X and work from there. At which point maybe you should be looking for the term "white papers"

Comment: "N A McMahon" - Doing incremental research, standing on a giant shoulders, ... I get it. This is what millions of annually published papers are about. But then, they complain that the number of 'disruptive' research papers has diminished over the years.

Comment: @TheMatrixEquation-balance Besides for perhaps some cases in mathematics where outlining a problem that is both interesting and difficult is seen to have quite a lot of value even without a solution, I'm struggling to think of many papers that are *disruptive* without having *data* to support them.

Comment: @BryanKrause - It took several decades to find the value behind Einstein's theory of general relativity.

Comment: @TheMatrixEquation-balance, no it didn't. The perihelion motion of Mercury was known and couldn't be explained before general relativity which predicted the anomaly. The paper also predicted bending of light by gravity and gravitational redshift, both of which were tested within a decade.

Comment: @TheMatrixEquation-balance, you aren't being stymied because of politics, you are being stymied because of best practices in academia. In academia you can't just throw out an idea and get it published, you need to support your idea with solid evidence for it to be considered a valuable contribution and worthy of publishing. This is different to politics where you can throw out ideas and say we should look into it.

Comment: And just a word of warning, you are displaying some symptoms of being a crackpot. I don't believe you are/should be labelled as a crackpot and are simply someone who doesn't know the how/why of academia, but its easy for me to see you sliding into that category in the future. If this happens you'll find very cold reception from academics because it is often a waste of time/frustrating to interact with crackpots. You'll probably also start feeling that this stack exchange is more hostile as well. The main thing to do to avoid it is probably to ask why things are done this way.